# Fireplace with Curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, topology

I'm trying to build a fireplace with curves. I tried watching a YouTube video on this exact thing but the person didn't explain what they were doing well enough...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6umJMYJos10&t=14s

I had some ideas about how to go about this but have too many questions, like... how to build a profile for this? Do I build the curve and then convert it to a mesh to join with an extended cube for the 2 vertical pillars? Can I join a converted curve (to a mesh) then join that with another mesh like the cube? And many more...

Here's where I am... I have the fireplace reference scaled to 6 ft at the 2 outer corners of the base...

[image: Fireplace]

I'm not really even sure what to ask or what method or topology to pursue. Maybe I picked a reference that is too complex for me at this stage. I was thinking of maybe hiring a tutor to get me over the hump. Any help would be awesome. Thanks SO MUCH!

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use only curves? Models like this are usually constructed using "standard" hard surface modelling methods (such as loop cut, extrude, bevel, mirror, etc...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess I don't really need to focus on only curves after thinking about this some more. I guess I wasn't sure how to get some of the curves in the lower portion and upper mantle for the overall shape. Obviously, there will be curves needed for the front of the fireplace. In particular, the shapes extending below the mantle. But I think the best way, is to do like you said, and use mesh modeling and convert the necessary curves for those other shapes later to mesh.

Comment: Is it possible to join converted curves to the existing mesh? For example, Do you see the curved mesh near the bottom of the left and right pillar shapes just slightly upward from the bottom edge? How would I do add a curve shape to go between the traditional mesh of the blocky base and the rest of the "pillar"? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but curved surfaces for things like this are usually accomplished using a Subdivision Surface Modifier, and appropriate supporting geometry - to get a better hold on what method to use, try watching a few videos like this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHbMqtKR_qo - it doesn't show you step by step how to do things (maybe if you slow it down a lot), but you'll get a good overall idea of how some of the shapes are constructed.